# How can I make this query in SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

this subquery works in SQL Server:

```
select systemUsers.name, 
    (select count(id) 
     from userIncidences 
     where idUser = systemUsers.id ) 
from systemUsers
```

How can It be made in SQL Compact?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT su.Name, COUNT(ui.ID)
FROM systemUsers su
LEFT JOIN userIncidences ui ON ui.idUser = su.ID
GROUP BY su.Name
```

[Edit:]
I originally had an INNER JOIN just like Tomalak, but I realized that this would exclude users with no incidents, rather than show them with a 0 count.  That might even be what you want, but it doesn't match your original.

Comment: Deleted mine, there would be no use having two identical answers.

Answer (score 10):

There are cases when you can't avoid a subquery, for instance if you have to include calculated columns that use data from the current and the previous row. Consider this query, for instance:

```
SELECT     
     (Current.Mileage - Last.Mileage)/Quantity as MPG
FROM         
     GasPurchases AS Current
     LEFT OUTER JOIN GasPurchases AS Last
     ON Last.Date =
        (SELECT MAX(PurchaseDate)
        FROM GasPurchases
        WHERE PurchaseDate < Current.PurchaseDate)
```

It will cause a parsing error:

> SQL Execution Error.
>
> Error Source: SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
>   Error Message: There was an error parsing the query.

I found [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/3a6351a2-6c10-4595-9b50-2ad4dc54470b/) on MSDN that has a workaround. By changing the subquery so that it returns a set instead of a scalar value, I was able to save and run the following query.

```
SELECT     
     (Current.Mileage - Last.Mileage)/Quantity as MPG
FROM         
     GasPurchases AS Current
     LEFT OUTER JOIN GasPurchases AS Last
     ON Last.Date IN
        (SELECT MAX(PurchaseDate)
        FROM GasPurchases
        WHERE PurchaseDate < Current.PurchaseDate)
```

Comment: Thankyou, I found this very useful :-)  I cannot however get a set based subquery to work in the following style "SELECT Consultant.Id, Consultant.Firstname, Consultant.Lastname FROM (SELECT Id, Firstname, Lastname FROM Consultant_Consultant) AS Consultant".  Am I doing something wrong?  Or does this style of query not work in SQL CE?

Comment: This is a nested query, not a subquery. I am not sure about the limitations in CE. Your example does not actually do anything, so I can't suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,  DoctaJonez, I found your little post the most helpful with my subquery. Your syntax seems to work with SQL Server Compact v3.5. Here is the query I tried (which works).

By the way, the hardcoded value you see (38046), I know at the time of running the query

```
insert into tLink (start,stop,associativeobject,linktype,id,name,guid,createTime,modifyTime,externalID,description,linkLabel,LinkDetails)
select newtable.id,stop,associativeobject,linktype,newtable.id,name,guid,createTime,modifyTime,externalID,description,linkLabel,LinkDetails from tLink l, (select id, '38046' as newid from tObject Where name = 'Step 1' and id <> '38046') as newtable
where l.start = newtable.newid and start in (38046)
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this? (using Northwind.Order Details]

The Code Snippet:

```
SELECT     [Unit Price] * Quantity AS Cost,

[Unit Price] * Quantity * 1.25 AS CostWithVAT
FROM         [Order Details]
```

Source  [Airline Reservation System Project](http://freedownloadbcamcaproject.in/ProjectView.aspx?RefID=77&title=Airline-Reservation-System-Project&pageno=webpage_1)