# SQL Server Compact Edition delete with inner join

Tags: sql-server-ce-3.5

Is it possible to use delete with inner join in SQL Server Compact Edition? What is the CE equivalent of this SQL Server query?

```
delete a from employee a inner join department b 
on a.departmentID=b.departmentID where b.departmentStatus='closed'
```

Comment: sorry, column names were wrong, i updated the query now.

Comment: sql server ce does not support sub query.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't support joins or subqueries, what does it support? Have you considered using Express instead of Compact?

Comment: It supports joins but not subquery. Sql server ce is restricted compared to desktop versions because it is used on mobile devices. Normally joins work in mssqlce, i am asking if it is possible to run a query like above.

Comment: If you know so much about what CE supports and doesn't support, why are you asking us if the above query will work? Did you *run* the query? What happened?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438548/sql-server-ce-can-i-delete-top-or-only-1-record-from-table-that-matches-my-query) seems to imply that delete via subquery works fine in SQL Server CE. What happened when you ran my query? Or did you not try that one either?

Comment: Sorry, my problem was using "=" before subquery. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645631/subquery-in-sql-server-compact-edition) shows it is possible to use subquery. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yeah, the subquery I showed - which you quickly discarded - used `IN`, not `=`.